# Are there any commercial nodes available so my transactions won't show my IP address?

Tags: client, privacy, network, relay, commercial

Oftentimes my own IP address shows up as the "Relayed by ip" piece of data reported by Blockchain.info.

Is there a commercial node available that I can conract with to act as relay so that my IP won't be known?  (and has as part of the agreement their assurance to not log IPs for transactions)?

I know there are certain well connected nodes that I can connect to, but I don't have the guarantee from them that they aren't collecting and sharing my IP info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitcoin will run over Tor. There [an article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Tor) on the Bitcoin wiki that explains the process.

Just install Tor and let it set up a proxy on its default IP (127.0.0.1) and port (9050).

For bitcoind, use the flag `--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050`.

For the GUI client, under `Options`, check `Connect through socks4 proxy`. Set the proxy IP to `127.0.0.1` and the port to `9050`.